# pass and check parameters in bootstrap modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, gsp

I have a bootstrap modal that is triggered by two links in the same page and i want to pass some parameter that inform the dialog from which element it has been triggered. so i can check this parameter in my dialog gsp tempalte.

first link

```
 <a href="#" id="editCourseModal" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCourseModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

second one button:

```
<button type="button" class="form-group btn btn-md btn-default" 
   data-toggle="modal" data-target="#createCourseModal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false">
```

modal dialog:

```
<div id="createCourseModal"  tabindex="-1" role="dialog" arialabelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body edit-content">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to check this parameter in my dialog ( g:if test="this parameter" ) so i can implement, hide and show some html elements based on this.
is it possible to do that? has anyone some other idea to solve this issue otherwise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a data attribute to each of the trigger buttons with the parameter you want to send through and do something like

```
$('#createCourseModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal

  var parameter = button.data('yourDataAttributeName') // Extract info from data-* attributes

  var modal = $(this)
  if (parameter == X) {
      modal.find('.modal-title').text('Clicked by X');
  } else {
      modal.find('.modal-title').text('Clicked by Y');
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside of loading the modal with data attributes, you could use jQuery to open the modal on a certain click of an element.

For example, let's say you had two anchor links:

```
<a href="#" id="link1"></a>
<a href="#" id="link2"></a>
```

You could use open the modal like this:

```
$('#link1').click(function() {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    // Here you could hide/show certain elements, and change this for #link2
});
```

Or, you could just have two modals.

Answer (score 0):

You can add **data-id** accordingly to your button and link capture that property using j-query.

```
$(document).on("click", ".openModal", function () {
     var clickedBy = $(this).data('id');
     $(".modal-body").html(clickedBy)
});
```

Find the below link for the above question

http://plnkr.co/edit/5EzNaDm1Z5SsXWngGULI?p=preview